# Why is Less Than or Equal To (<=) Returning False For Equal Number (C++)

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I have created a simple function that calculates the BMI of a person given the weight and height (metric). Everything works fine except when the BMI is 30. It's returning Obese instead of Overweight even though I have put less than or equal to (<=). I have found a fix for it, but I am not understanding why this fixes it. The fix I found is casting the `bmi` variable to an integer. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

std::string bmi(double w, double h){
    double bmi = w / (h * h);
    std::cout << bmi << '\n';
    if(bmi <= 18.5){
        return "Underweight";
    }else if(bmi <= 25){
        return "Normal";
    }else if(bmi <= 30){ // BUG, fix: cast bmi to (int), but WHY ?
        return "Overweight";
    }else{ // bmi > 30.0
        return "Obese";
    }
}

int main(){
    std::cout << bmi(86.7, 1.7) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the double is probably represented as `30.0000000x` and when you cast to int its rounded down to `30`

Comment: @cigien Didn't know about that, thank you!

Comment: @TonyTannous Yep I understood that, but then how would one compare to a double number without casting it to an integer?

Comment: add an epsilon to the comparison.

Comment: You'd add a fudge factor.  `bmi <= 30.0 + 0.01`

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, I understand the issue now!

Comment: I think nearly every programmer learns this lesson.  It takes some experience with the idiosyncrasies of floating point to be aware of its pitfalls.